# Ruby on Rails - Enum vs Boolean for ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Working on a RoR app. Think Tinder for art with a little basic AI. As you like or dislike art the app will show you art that you will hopefully like more based on other users’ preferences.

I have a model (ArtworkViews) to record what users think of each piece of art (Artworks). It currently has the following setup:

```
user_id: integer
artwork_id: integer
liked: boolean
```

When a user clicks on the like/dislike button a record is created with liked set to true/false.

Then I need to do some stuff to figure out what artwork to show next.  I’ll work on that soon (and probably will be back here with more questions).

My question for now is: should liked be a boolean or is an enum integer (:liked, :disliked) better when it comes to my ActiveRecord queries that are to come? Production will be using PG via Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

I think boolean is good for your Active Record if the status is only just liked and not liked.
But if in the future you need more status beyond liked and disliked, you should go for enum. Because adding more status doesn't affect your current queries.